# Final Descriptor in SIFT

Tags: computer-vision, sift

I am new to computer vision and start to learn a very popular topic in the computer vision community, which is SIFT. But I am confused with one implementation detail:

After the detection of a key point, we have to construct 4 by 4 local histograms, serving as the final SIFT descriptor, right? Each local histogram contains the orientation of a local neighborhood of 4 by 4 pixels. So overall we have 16 times 16 equals 256 pixels, which are within a neighborhood around the key point. So this neighborhood is a 16 by 16 grid of pixels.

But how is this neighborhood determined in details? Is the neighborhood rotated according to the orientation of key point? Are pixels within this 256-pixel neighborhood separate according to the scale at which the key point is detected?

Thanks for all coming help!

Answer (score 0):

First, SIFT keypoints are extracted at multiple scales. The descriptors are computed using the respective scale. So, I would not say 'pixels' since it can be ambiguous. For your question, I would like to quote the [original paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~malik/cs294/lowe-ijcv04.pdf) (Section 6.1):

> First the image gradient magnitudes
>   and orientations are sampled around the keypoint location, using the scale of the
>   keypoint to select the level of Gaussian blur for the image.
>
> In order to achieve orientation
>   invariance, the coordinates of the descriptor and the gradient orientations are rotated relative
>   to the keypoint orientation.
>
> A Gaussian weighting function with σ equal to one half the width of the descriptor window
>   is used to assign a weight to the magnitude of each sample point.

I hope this answers your question. Please do not hesitate to ask if something is unclear.